# succulent identification :)

Tags: identification, succulents

I've been trying to identify this succulent i got a while back so I could know how to propogate it but I can't find similar ones on google :( It's flat-ish with very plump leaves (that have tips) can anyone help? thank you!!

[image: it's kinda flat and has very plump leaves?]

[image: see, it's flat but has tipped leaves]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest *Graptopetalum filiferum*, the extended tips are quite unusual amongst rosette forming plants:

[image]

Source: https://worldofsucculents.com/graptopetalum-filiferum/